# Center icon in the middle of an image in a justified gallery layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) library to justify the images, I am also using a CSS hover effect on the images that displays a FontAwesome icon when hovered over.

The problem is, the icon is appearing in a different position over each image because each image has a different dimensions imposed on it by the Justified Gallery plugin to fit the grid.

I would like to have the icon appear in the same fixed position at the center of each image.

Here's how the grid looks like and how the icon appears on a smaller and bigger thumbnail.

**JS Fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/halnex/3shtoyzz/3/

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="mygallery" class="global-height scrollable">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img alt="Title 1" src="assets/images/posts/thumbs/post-1.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
            <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img alt="Title 1" src="assets/images/posts/thumbs/post-2.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
            <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img alt="Title 1" src="assets/images/posts/thumbs/post-3.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
            <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(48, 152, 157, 0.1);
}

.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
    transform: translateY(45px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(5px);
    transform: translateY(5px);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 100px 50px;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;*/
}
```

The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mygallery").justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight : 155,
        lastRow : 'justify',
        margins : 0,
        captions: false
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: The code you provided does not match the picture. https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/trgLLr5h/

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the javascript. I edited my post. You have to include Justified Gallery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try centering with `display: flex`

https://jsfiddle.net/ramtob/3shtoyzz/4/

I added to classes `.overlay` and `.hovereffect` this flex centering code:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

I also made the images (rather than the icons) positioned absolute, so that they do not interfere with the centering of the icons.

Answer (score 0):

```
.info{
    transform: translateY(-80%);
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: try put !important

Answer (score 0):

Change your `margin value` for `class .info` to auto i.e. for `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```
.hovereffect a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 100px auto;/*Made changes over-here*/
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mygallery").justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight : 155,
        lastRow : 'justify',
        margins : 0,
        captions: false
    });
});
```

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(48, 152, 157, 0.1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
  transform: translateY(45px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/bower_components/justified-gallery/dist/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/bower_components/justified-gallery/dist/css/justifiedGallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
">

<div id="mygallery" class="global-height scrollable">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img alt="Title 1" src="http://placehold.it/242x172" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img alt="Title 1" src="http://placehold.it/256x172" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img alt="Title 1" src="http://placehold.it/115x172" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="color: white;"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```